# Magento can't login Admin panel error 500

Tags: php, magento

I have a live running website developed using magento (1.8.1.0). The frontend is working fine but (from this morning) when I try to log in the admin panel I get the "http error 500" even if I use a wrong password or username.

Foreach login attempt the magento error log reports:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   loadByUsername() on a non-object in
>   $MAGENTO_ROOT/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Admin_Model_User.php on line 408

the corresponding code in Mage_Admin_Model_User.php is:

```
406>  public function loadByUsername($username)
407>     {
408>       $this->setData($this->getResource()->loadByUsername($username));
409>       return $this;
410>     }
```

I have just deleted the cache and session directories but the problem remains.

what could have happened ? how can I fix it ?

Comment: getResource() returned a non-object, for whatever reason.

Comment: Check var/cache/ permissions/ownership

Comment: Are you doing any overrides to override the User model? Any recent extensions installed? Have you also tried clearing the cache folder?

Comment: the problem may have been caused by an upgrade of all cache type in cache management section.

Answer (score 0):

> (from this morning)

- Was there any update on server (hosting)? I would try to search on official Magento site if it is a common bug (other users can face it after update too)
- Test copy of installation (ftp + db) on different server (hosting) in order to see if the problem persists.
- Try to [Google it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23632/error-after-login-to-magento-on-core-mage-admin-model-user-php-on-line-437) similar to this (`$MAGENTO_ROOT/httpdocs/includes/src/` is your site specific so Google will find nothing relevant):

> loadByUsername() on a non-object in Mage_Admin_Model_User.php on line
>   408

Answer (score 0):

Thank's all for the contribute, the problem is solved. It was very sneaky.

I've found in the directory **app/code/core/Mage/** the directory *"Admin"* renamed as *"Admin  "* (Admin with 2 spaces). Moreover this files were missing:  **app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml** and **app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Helper/Data.php**.

After renaming the directory, restoring files, deleting cache and session, the problem is solved.
It was probably originated by a cache update in Cache Management section.

Comment: A cache update would most certainly not rename a directory.  This sounds like an accidental rename of a folder.  You may want to consider moving to a git/deployment flow to help prevent/make visible these kinds of problems.